# Sanity and NextJs -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')

Tags: next.js, sanity

Im trying to create a portfolio site for myself using sanity on the backend. The site is working and the DB is set up and working using Sanity studio, but I cant get it to connect properly on the backend using Next.

Here is my connection file:

```
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";
import createImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";


export const client = createClient({
  projectId: "p079sml5",
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2023-01-31",
  useCdn: false,
});
```

I'll be hiding a lot of this in env files but for the purposes of debugging I've left the info in.

And here is one of my endpoints:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import { client } from "sanity";

import { Social } from "./typings";

const query = groq`
*[_type == "social"]
`;

type Data = {
  socials: Social[];
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const socials: Social[] = await client.fetch(query);

  res.status(200).json({ socials });
}
```

As per the title, when trying to make the call on http://localhost:3000/api/getSocials, I get the following error: error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/getSocials.ts:15:70)

Fetch appears on the autofill, along with the other methods, so it would appear that its been imported "correctly". The error suggests that that its the client that is the issue but cant figure out why.

Thanks in advance

Ive tried, using my dev environment, with the associated project id etc but no joy.

UPDATE: Fixed, I just moved the client file into a different folder, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Follow this doc https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-sanity

Or setup this repo in new folder and update it's config (/lib/config.js) file with your sanity details then check... previously it was worked for me.